# Why isn't my android working properly?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3

A couple months ago I tried putting CyanogenMod on my sprint galaxy s3. I used the one click cyanogen installer on my windows PC.

I don't remember why, but the install didn't fully flash because unless I'm going into recovery mode I never see the cyanogen boot up screen. I have gone into `About Phone` but I can't find anything telling me that Cyanogen is actually running or even on the device.

Ever since I did try to flash this ROM my phone hasn't been able to fully function. Certain apps that I previously had or reinstalled off of the play store either don't work or certain functions within the app don't work. All I know is that when I enter recovery mode it does show clockworkmod as my recovery.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the flash purely failed, or that you dirty flashed (flashing without clearing the cache/data) the ROM.

Seeing as you have access to recovery:

- I'd suggest that you download a new CM ROM (Lollipop-5.0.2) from the [XDA Developer Forums](http://www.xda-developers.com/)
- Download the corresponding Google Apps package (i.e. for PA GApps for Android L)
- Place both of the .zip files on your external SD card
- Boot your phone into recovery mode and Wipe Data (Factory Reset). Also wipe all caches (Dalvik inclusively)
- Install both .zips. First the ROM, and then the GApps package
- Wipe the Dalvik Cache one more time for good measure
- Boot the device and enjoy CM